# Fields: Fundamental and Physical, yet Unobservable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, measurement-problem, observables

I'm currently working through Robert Klauber's Student Friendly Quantum Field Theory, which by the way is much more accessible than other texts like, say, Peskin and Schroeder, for others also coming into QFT via the self-study path.

Anyhow, he mentioned something that never really jumped out at me before, like it is now: **Fields are un-observable**.

Also, I got caught up on the notion of how something can be un-observable, yet also physical. And, how we can call fields fundamental, while at the same time fields are undetectable, even in principle?

Curious what others make of this.

Comment: If fields were unobservable, even in principle, then all field theories would be equivalent.  This is not the case.

Comment: It might help if you provide a quote with some context around "fields are un-observable", so we can better understand what the author meant.

Comment: Why have you concluded that fields are unobservable? Can we not measure amplitudes i.e. VEVs of combinations of fields? There are superselection rules though...

Comment: Here's a simpler example.  There's no way to measure energy.  One can measure location, mass, and time, and from those calculate gravitational potential energy and kinetic energy, but there are no direct energy measurements.  So is energy real?  The fact that it is conserved makes it seem pretty real.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at Wheeler-Feynman electrodynamics or in general action at a distance formulations of field theories. They only include particle degrees of freedom and are at least on a classical level empirically equivalent (Though there seems to be a problem with the initial values which is only partially solved).

Answer (score 0):

> Also, I got caught up on the notion of how something can be un-observable, yet also physical. And, how we can call fields fundamental, while at the same time fields are undetectable, even in principle?

Quantum field theory is a mathematical model, with creation and annnihilation operators operating on quantum fields . These do not have to be the fields of fundamental particles but cover many problems and are called [effective field theories.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_field_theory#Other_examples) In this sense the "field" on which the creation and annihilation operators operate can be various ,( starting from the harmonic oscillator ground state).

In particle physics the ground state  is the wave function of the free particle solution for the respective particle fields from the [table of elementary particles.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg)

*Wave functions are not directly observable.*  It is only  their complex conjugate squared which gives  probability density distributions.

A concrete example is the [harmonic oscillator](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-61-physical-chemistry-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT5_61F13_Lecture9.pdf) , using its solutions one can define a field theory for creation and annihilation operators:

[image: annhihi]

> This is astonishingly convenient.  It presages a form of operator algebra that proceeds without ever looking at the form of ψ(x) and does not require direct evaluation of integrals

The fields  existence is implied by the creation and annihilation operators on these ground states, which will describe the particles, and particles are observable.

To sum up, mathematical models fitting observations have components which are not directly observable, but are necessary for *calculating measurable distributions.* In particle physics  calculations are made with Feynman diagrams which describe the perturbative expansion of crossections etc.

Fundamental but not physical: The  (x,y,z) coordinates mapping a terrain are unobservable, a mathematical concept, nevertheless the map is described by the functions of (x,y,z), and the (x,y,z) concept is the context for having a map.  Particle fields provide the fundamental context on which the physical observables of particles can be modeled.

Comment: Creation and annihilation operators *are* the quantum fields which operate on Fock space

Comment: The ground state is the state with no particles, not a wave function.

Comment: @innisfree mathematically, so that one can calculate the feynman diagrams , it is the ground state wave function on which the creation and annihilation operators operate. ( the operators are differentials that have to operate on something, and give the expectations value of one if a creation operator or -1 if an annihilation one)

Comment: @innisfree look at the harmonic oscillator which started the whole field: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-61-physical-chemistry-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT5_61F13_Lecture9.pdf

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about. the creation/annihilation operators do indeed operate on something, and that something is a Fock space, not a wave function from QM.

Comment: @innisfree  maybe you should go a bit deeper than an algebraic format.

Comment: Anna, while I mostly agree with what you say, IF wave functions and/or fields are not observable in principle, ever, I don't think we can say their existence is implied.  The best we can say is they are mathematical constructs that work, but we can never know for sure if they are truly real ... whatever "real" means.  I guess if you're like Roger Penrose and believe all math exists out there in some kind of Platonic Reality we could say they exist, but we've left physics behind at that point ;-)

Comment: @EthanT  In my last paragraph I illustrate what is implied by the example of space coordinates.  Without a framework the physical measurement cannot be modeled. The existence of a framework is implied in the model, the way that the existence of a language is implied in what I am writing. In other words meta-levels. I am not a platonist. The mathematics exists and is a tool for describing and predicting data.

Comment: @innisfree  have a look here also https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04182.pdf

Comment: @annav i don't need to read 'Feynman Diagrams for Beginners'. there are major errors about the very basics of QFT in your text. and that's it.  not that interested in continuing this discussion.

Comment: @annav understood, but only a small subset of math correlates, or applies to, physical reality.  Just because something can be mathematically modeled, does not mean it is part of physical reality.  Therefore, unless we can empirically confirm the existence of a field, via measurement, which the text claims is impossible in principle, then I don't think we can say fields exist for sure.

Comment: @annav  In addition, just because a mathematical model can be accurately used to make physical predictions does not mean our interpretation of it represents reality.  For example, Plato's Epicycles can be used to very accurately model the solar system, in that very accurate predictions can be made with it, but we know for sure the solar system is not geocentric!  This mathematical model does not correspond to physical reality even if it can be used to model it and make predictions.

Comment: @EthanT I do not disagree, but the example of epicycles is unfortunate :). Mathematically the epicycles are there , they come out of planetaria fits when the coordinate system is changed to the earth rest system, and they are there in the night sky over the year plotting little  measurable cycles. The model fits the data, it is just that newtonian physics gives a much larger scope of fitting data.   And yes, physics uses a subset of mathematics, and defines as *real* what can be *measured* directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses everyone, much appreciated.  Anna, thanks for the detailed response, I have come to some of the conclusions you have stated, still, it leaves me feeling a bit uneasy as it's not a very satisfying conclusion.

Here is a quote of what is stated in the text I refer to:

*"In QFT there are two kinds of operators.  One kind is the usual one from NRQM and RQM representing dynamical variables of classical theory, such as the Hamiltonian (energy), the 3-momentum operator, charge, etc.  The other kind comprises creation and destruction operators.*

*The first kind, when operating on an eigenstate, reproduces the original eigenstate, multiplied by an eigenvalue.  The second kind changes the state to another state ... note that operators of this kind do not have eigenvalues, since their operation on a state changes that state, rather than reproducing it .. and hence they are generally not observable."*

From another chapter:

*"Recall ... fields such as phi, psi, A_mu are themselves not observable.  They cannot be measured directly (we prove they have zero expectation value in Chapter 7).  But properties of fields like energy, momentum and charge are measurable.  Our dynamical variable operators, which include number operators, reflect this.  They typically have non-zero expectation value*

(phi is the scalar field of the Klein-Gordon equation, psi the spinor field of electrons and A_u the vector field of QED)

I guess we get into the whole, "what is real" debate.  But, are fields "real", or are they as real as absolute space-time was in Newtonian Physics, in that they're just an approximation, or partial appearance, of some deeper underlying reality?  Absolute space-time doesn't exist anywhere in nature, any more than a perfect circle does?  Can the same be said for fields?